# Ionic modal hangs while opening and closing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating a Cordova ionic App. I have created a modal in it. It is hanging while opening and closing. All modal behaving same throughout the app. Below is one of them :

**NewModal.html**

```
        <ion-modal-view> <ion-content class="padding"
            has-bouncing="false">
        <form name="labelForm">
            <label style="display: inline;"> Width: </label> <input
                class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="value.width" min=10
                max=1200 name="width" required="required" id="width1" /> <label
                style="display: inline;">Height: </label> <input class="form-control"
                type="number" ng-model="value.height" min=10 id="height1" max=600
                name="height" required />

            <button title="Create" class="button button-full btn-orange"
                type="submit" on-tap="submitted=true;createLabel(labelForm.$valid);">Create</button>
        </ion-content> </ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: can you try without effects i mean, by removing ' has-bouncing="false" ' from ion-content tag

Comment: please make a plunker of fiddle